# Pass newly created object to partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, partial-views

This is the part of my method where i create a new object and save it to the DB:

```
 var db = new ArtContext();

            var nyArt = new ArtWork()
            {
                ArtLink = name,

            };

            db.ArtWorks.Add(nyArt);
            db.SaveChanges();

            PartialView("_CreatedArt", nyArt);
```

As you can see, I try to pass my new object to a partial view. My view where I hope to render the partial:

```
@Html.Partial("_CreatedArt", Model)
```

However, nothing happens (no view renders). Is it maybe because it takes some time for the DB to save the new object or am I maybe doing something else wrong?

EDIT:

Index view, where i want to render the partial:

```
@model Heroz.Models.ArtWork
@using Heroz.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
        <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

    <button onclick="drawShapes()"></button>

        <!--Canvas1-->
         <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300" style="background-color: slategray;"></canvas>
         <input type="button" id="btnSaves" name="btnSaves" value="Save the canvas to server" />
         <input type="hidden" name="imageData" id="imageData" />

        <!--Canvas2-->
         @Html.Partial("_CreatedArt", Model)
```

Partial view:

```
@model Heroz.Models.ArtWork

<div id="canvas" width="400" height="300" style="background-color: grey;">
    <img src="@Model.ArtLink"/>
</div>
```

The class im working with:

```
namespace Heroz.Models
{
    public class ArtWork
    {


        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ArtLink { get; set; }

    }

    public class ArtContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ArtWork> ArtWorks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What om trying to do i short is, dreaw a picture with the canvas, upload it to the DB (this works fine), then asap show the picture in the partial.

EDIT AJAX:

```
 $("#btnSaves").click(function () {

        var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
        image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../../Home/UploadImageS",
            data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('Image saved successfully !');
            }
        });
    });
```

Complete Action:

```
static string path = Path.GetTempFileName();

        public ActionResult UploadImageS(string imageData)
        {
            string fileNameWitPath = path + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(" ", "- ").Replace(":", "") + ".png";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
                    bw.Write(data);
                    bw.Close();
                }
            }


            string link = UploadImage(fileNameWitPath);

            JObject o = JObject.Parse(link);

            string name = (string)o.SelectToken("data.link");

            var db = new ArtContext();

            var nyArt = new ArtWork()
            {
                ArtLink = name,

            };

            db.ArtWorks.Add(nyArt);
            db.SaveChanges();
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileNameWitPath);

            /*RedirectToAction("Index","Home");*/

            PartialView("_CreatedArt", nyArt);

        }
```

Comment: Pleas add your view code and action code completly

Comment: Do you put a breakepoint in your partial view?

Comment: yes, it does not get hit..

Comment: But this part contains the right values:
PartialView("_CreatedArt", nyArt);

Comment: put a breakpoint on   @Html.Partial("_CreatedArt", Model) and check Model in watch.check it's value befor render your prtial view

Comment: It does not seem as if that line gets hit when i click:
<input type="button" id="btnSaves" name="btnSaves" value="Save the canvas to server" />

Comment: You mean when in your action you return PartialView("_CreatedArt", nyArt); it does not worke?

Comment: well actually that line works fine...ig I hover over nyArt I can see that it contains what I expect. But after that, It does not get rendered in the partial view.

Comment: When you return a partial view in your action.server pass rendered html from partial view to client.you must call your action with ajax and replace  server response in your html code.How do you call your action.and pleas add your action code completly

Comment: Please see edit for the AJAX that calls the method.

Comment: Seems like your action doesn't have a return value for the UploadImageS action.. Are you meaning to say return PartialView("_CreatedArt", nyArt)?  Calling the method won't do anything unless you return it in your action method.

Comment: sorry, im trying different stuff here..Right now I End the method with 
: return  RedirectToAction("Index",new
            {
                model = nyArt,

            });

Trying to pass the new model to the index-view..

Comment: RedirectToAction is a redirect (HTTP 302) which means you can't pass complex model data (only simple values like strings or ints).  The method expects an action name and / or a route value dictionary or some combination of the two.  See this link for available options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx  If you want to pass model data, consider calling another controller action directly.

Comment: Aha thats interesting and mig actually work in my case...all i want to pass is the string containing the url. I notices that my model contained "null"...Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your return a partial view  you can replace html response to an element html like :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../../Home/UploadImageS",
            data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#ContainerId").html(msg);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This seems like the best soultion for me, Thank you ver much!

Answer (score 1):

You can chain your controller actions in MVC instead of redirecting.

```
public class MyController {

    public ActionResult MainIndex() {

        FunModel myModel = new FunModel();
        return View("Index", myModel);
    }

    public ActionResult PostAction(string id) {
        //Do db work
        //Do additional work

        // Re-use the logic for loading the main view
        ActionResult result = MainIndex();
        //You can access view model data like this
        FunModel myModel = (FunModel)ViewData.Model;
        myModel.UpdatedId = id;
        return result;
    }
}
```

And you can access the view data from a previous action by reading it out of the ViewData.Model property.

Comment: Thank you! Im gonna have a look at this in the morning.