# Using Ajax to render partial view, taking an object as parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First of, I got some help from nice people yesterday helping me decide on what approach to take: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832038/pass-newly-created-object-to-partial-view/24834225#24834225`

Summary:
I got some Ajax calling a method that creates an object. I would like to use the Ajax success-message to replace the content in a div with my new object. This is the Ajax:

```
$("#btnSaves").click(function () {

        var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
        image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../../Home/UploadImageS", //THIS METHOD CREATES AN OBJECT
            data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (?) {
                HERE I NEED CODE THAT RENDERS A PARTIAL VIEW PASSING THE OBJECT AS A PARAMETER.
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the controller, I'm not sure what its return value should be:

```
public ActionResult UploadImageS(string imageData)
        {
            string fileNameWitPath = path + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(" ", "- ").Replace(":", "") + ".png";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
                    bw.Write(data);
                    bw.Close();
                }
            }

            string link = UploadImage(fileNameWitPath);

            JObject o = JObject.Parse(link);

            string name = (string)o.SelectToken("data.link");

            var db = new ArtContext();

            var nyArt = new ArtWork()
            {
                ArtLink = name,

            };

            db.ArtWorks.Add(nyArt);
            db.SaveChanges();
            Return ??
        }
    }
```

I'm not that comfortable working with Ajax so I would also appreciate some explanation if possible.

This is what my method returns:

```
return  View("TestView",nyArt);
```

The testview, created without layout:

@model Heroz.Models.ArtWork

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TestView</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="@Model.ArtLink"/> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when I put a brekpoint at:

```
return  View("TestView",nyArt);
```

I does not step into the ""TestView", It goes directly to the _Layout.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on that? Is it the method in my controller that should return Json or should the Ajax return Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are seeking is some HTML back from your AJAX call that you can then render inside an existing element. Is that correct?

If so, the easiest way is to construct a view that contains the correct model, and return it from your method. So you would write up a view that contains *only* the HTML you wish to return (no layout page or anything), then return that as normal with `return View();`.

Let's say (for example) that you wanted to return some HTML that used the `nyImage` object you created in your action. You would create a view with the HTML and specify the model you want to use (in this case, the type of `nyImage`).

**EDIT:** I have used razor to output the `name` property of the model, which I believe is the full link to the art on the imagehosting site.

```
@model ArtWork

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div>
    <img src="@Model.name" />
</div>
```

Then you would save this view as whatever you want to call it, let's say `TestView`. Then in your action method you would return this view, passing in the model:

```
return View("TestView", nyArt);
```

This will return a `ViewResult` that contains the HTML generated by the view/model.

On the client you will return this data as HTML, which you can then append to a page element if you wish to display it:

```
success: function (ret) {
    //do something with ret here
    $('#myDiv').html(ret);
    HERE I NEED CODE THAT RENDERS A PARTIAL VIEW PASSING THE OBJECT AS A PARAMETER.
}
```

The above snippet will *replace the contents* of `#myDiv` with the HTML returned from teh AJAX call.

Comment: Thank you! This is what im trying to achieve:
In my index.cshtml I have a canvas on whch I can draw a picture (like paint). Then, when I press a button, the "Art" gets saved to the database in form of an href to an imagehost-site- This Parts works fine. But what try to do is to pass the newly created "art" to a partial view.

Comment: OK the code example will work for you then. In your new view (which I called `TestView` you would set the `src` attribute of the image to the link returned from the hosting site - this will then display the image when the returned HTML is rendered. I'll update the example.

Comment: Thank you very much! Im sure this is the right way to go about It but when I step through the code, it does not reach the sucess-mehod, everthings works fine until this line in the _layout(where I have the ajax):
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

The it "jumps out". Should I maybe place the Ajax elsewhere?

Comment: Are you saying that the error occurs in the _Layout page when your AJAX method runs?

Comment: It goes like this:
The object gets created and returns this: return View("TestView", nyArt);
This works fine and i can step through the "TestView" and see that the href is where it should be. Next the code goes to the _layout but it never reaches the AJAX this time. 
After this line: @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) 
The code gets out of the _Layout and im back on my page wth nothing new rendered.

Comment: You probably have a default layout page set in the `ViewStart` page. Check my edit in the view code to set the layout page to null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57597/discussion-between-katstevens-and-user2915962).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it to work with the help of this code..For some resonit worked when i removed @{
    Layout = null;
}...